# How do I use Fabricjs to change image color?

Tags: image-processing, fabricjs

I'm trying to use Fabric.js filters to change a single color of an image.  For example, I'm trying this to change the red parts of an image to green:

```
image.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Blend({
    color: '#ff0000',
    mode: 'subtract'
}));
image.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Blend({
    color: '#00ff00',
    mode: 'add'
}));
image.applyFilters(_canvas.renderAll.bind(_canvas));
```

But what is happening is that the black borders are all being changed to green as well.  Is there some way to do this using the built-in filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blend filter are not used for color substitution.

Addition

This blend mode simply adds pixel values of one layer with the other. In case of values above 1 (in the case of RGB), white is displayed. "Linear Dodge" produces the same visual result. Since this always produces the same or lighter colors than the input it is also known as 'plus lighter'. A variant subtracts 1 from all end values, with values below 0 becoming black; this mode is known as 'plus darker'.

Subtract

This blend mode simply subtracts pixel values of one layer with the other. In case of negative values, black is displayed.

so if you have black border and red area:

first pass of red subctract transform the red in black and the black in black ( all zeroes ).  second pass transform the black ( all ) in green, adding FF to green channell of the black pixels.

to change color of an image you should create a custom filter that pixel per pixel detect red and write green over it.

Comment: i m searching an example with a color substitution filter.